# DELETE FROM LOOP issue

Tags: php, sql

When I run my code I get this error:

[image: Error1]

I've tested the SQL on my server and it correct which leads me to believe that it is the loop is incorrect.

I know about the security issues which I will fix next.

```
if(isset($_GET['rowID']))
    {
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM table WHERE  id="' . $_GET['rowID'] . '";';
        echo "<b>ECHO SQL<b><br>";
        echo $sql;


        if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) 
        {
            echo "Record deleted successfully";

        }
        else 
        {
            echo "<br> Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($connection);
        }


    }
```

Comment: *"DELETE FROM LOOP"* - what loop? and what's the real / full error?

Comment: you've an answer below; ask them. I moved on now.

Comment: The error is the if statment seems not to be running the SQL statment correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct GET variable `rowID` instead of `row` on line 3:

```
if(isset($_GET['rowID']))
{
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM table WHERE  id="' . $_GET['rowID'] . '";';
    echo "<b>ECHO SQL<b><br>";
    echo $sql;


    if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) 
    {
        echo "Record deleted successfully";

    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<br> Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($connection);
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm still having the same result

Comment: can you try a `var_dump($connection)` ? It seems that your connection is not correct...